# How to read python RSA Pem key correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa

I want to read a RSA public key from database. I am using rsa python lib. public key is stored as a text.

when i print type of key and it value i get (var name is pk) (`print(type(pk), pk)`):

```
<class 'bytes'> b'-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\\nMIIBCgKCAQEAmXSSnzrY2/z7zLZuF7KZZFP7mbmYEeRhpQsQfpEv4t/Fvz6/g5QO\\n79ZcGBd6wOxshGFSLYPAl1oB3GPNkwr+mdjqtSIXzhhvW9Xjjx4dIUVn7JrtsBXi\\nr7aG85HEYyk3LLBoWus9X+XJ/tiHlQzqY2o8+dO31X4HBeWzflczrNXN3ntGGf4S\\noAaqJKlkUSxdGexvJUhmli9x+CKQoojFHxHfq1IZldRMPb8O8N6RSZIA5t2n6vpw\\nGPx8tBm7Eub5nVi+sACHS6rLdAHcd+D4tBCjp9wp2dGu77/oRUI7aomRFRMmBf7/\\nZkHHzor2kGIZ3fYHEL7g+WkVsxqGXblG8QIDAQAB\\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\\n'
```

but when i use

```
 pubkey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(pk)
```

i get

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rsa/pem.py", line 77, in _pem_lines raise ValueError('No PEM start marker "%r" found' % pem_start) ValueError: No PEM start marker "b'-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----'" found
```

error all the time. Why is that? How to fix it?

I tried to make it work but no luck yet.

Comment: load_pkcs1 expects a string. so this should fix it pk_str = pk.decode() and then give the pk_str as argument to the pubkey = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(pk_str )

Comment: type + print : <class 'str'> -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIIBCgKCAQEAtMHeJ8MqgsINfgn9vmvjsdxNs37YubA8zcmTSfCSMEKxz6mwj5HE\nc3b6NjuEyWqifa4lsYuPhIDi6uhbHlg0xoEP/U9197aikXhedr8fkrUsnQaq4SFZ\n+q23T2xWYXXnGyufQEEOig+vr7b1pSBnZhrkSK9Qw3ASDhR10/MIpyZuO0jN0+rO\ntW5XsSKmqswBgD7Bw6ejODE45cpSEr+MFD5jx9MOY38BFt/f/7/Cu9/BvgSc0ABg\nxKjU6Q3A2hy51JE1ktAKpW0ApkWtcSPrnvhBmJpYH/SJziEdaP6t6Z4e5opKvjvw\nDfie6/94gysYXFi6BLM6n8bp/GmXZhri3QIDAQAB\n-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n    still same error

Comment: i don't know if i understand it correctly. Which `b` do i have to remove?  what escape code am I using?

Comment: `<class 'bytes'>` is a type of a variable. I double check it in print to make sure what type am I operating.

Comment: escape is like \n for making new line. but should i remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. the PEM seems to be badly encoded, or it is altered during the encoding / decoding process. Due to this the newline character has gone from `\n` to `\\n` in the above binary string;
2. you're handling the string as a binary string input, where the escape is **not** turned into an actual newline.

To fix this directly in code you can insert the following line before your `load_pkcs1` statement:

```
pk = pk.replace(b'\\n', b'\n').decode('ascii')
```

which should fix the encoding and unescape the newline characters.

Not sure if and why the PEM is stored as a binary string; the whole point of a PEM structure is that it is text instead of binary.

Comment: looks like working, thanks :D